# How can we address the security issues related to the executing of malicious codes?

Tags: transactions, security

Assume a malicious code exists in a contract (either written intentionally or not). Is there any mechanism to prevent such codes from being executed? Is it even possible to do the monitoring?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the context, I assume you're concerned about malicious code affecting the machine it runs on. This isn't an issue*, because EVM code runs in a very restrictive interpreter sandbox. Code has to be written using EVM instructions, which are limited to affecting the state of the virtual machine itself, and reading and writing blockchain state; by design, there's no way to access or influence the state of the machine it runs on. This is necessary both for security, and to ensure consensus.

** Barring vulnerabilities in the EVM itself, which are unlikely with common implementations, but perhaps more plausible with a JIT-based implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You can upgrade a contract based on the `DELEGATECALL` opcode and the `SUICIDE` opcode.
Obviously only a throughout pentesting can asses malicious code.

Comment: Is it even possible to implement some `anti-virus` or `anti-malware` to monitor the contracts before hand?

Comment: Yes you can run some static and dynamic analysis and find some typical holes in the contracts. Actually a good idea that someone runs this service and generates automatic reports...